What is the difference between the Law of X and the density function of a random variable X?
I'm starting to study probability theory and I'm confused about the difference between the Law of X and the density function. It seems to me that the density function is defined as 0 when P(X = k) is 0:
Here is what I don't understand
$$X : \Omega \to \mathbb{X}$$
$$P(X=k) = P(\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) = k) \text{ Probability of $k$}$$
(I don't use Latex, I use another language and don't know how to write that in latex so check the link to the image that SE won't allow be to embed)

The density or the cumulative distribution function are two equivalent way to define the law of probability followed by a random variable. When one refers to the law of $X$, it can either be one or the other? Not sure this is what you are asking though.

I have written two lines in LaTeX. By editing your question you can see how I did this and start learning LaTeX from there and continue writing your entire explanation in LaTeX. Have fun!

On a side note, your question might be poorly received if you do not use Latex. If you plan on using this site regularly, you should get used to it tutorial

Ok I found an answer: there is no difference.
What I was referring to was P(X = k), with a value in the reals that X can output. It was called when it was explained to me "Law of X", but then density and CDF were introduced and I started to confuse things.
Within the scope of a descrete r.v. X: $$ Law \space of \space X= (descrete) \space density = mass $$
At least I think.
